# Type '_' does not conform to protocol Decodable / Encodable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to retrieve some results from the iTunes API and wanted to write a struct for the APIResponse, and have a variable of type 'Result', but it doesn't seem to be working (and am not sure how to go about it all, if I should use a different type, scrap it, etc).

```
struct APIResponse: Codable {
    var apiResults: Result
}

struct APIResult: Codable {
    var songName: String
    var songID: Int
    var collectionName: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results = [APIResult]()
    
    func loadData() async {
        // Step 1: Creating the URL we want to read.
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=john+mayer&entity=song") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        // Step 2: Fetching the data for the URL.
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data) {
                results = decodedResponse.apiResults
            }
        } catch {
            print("Invalid data.")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.songID) { songItem in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(songItem.songName).font(.headline)
                Text(songItem.collectionName)
            }
        }.task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Am I going about it all the completely wrong way, or is it a simple fix?

I expected everything to work, as I google'd extensively and seemed to be calling the API correctly, but not sure what I should be doing besides

```
': Result'
```

Comment: `decodedResponse.apiResults` is not an array, compare the struct `APIResponse` definition with the definition of the `@State var results` property and you see that there is a mismatch, as a matter of fact you seem to have involved another type as well `Result` vs `APIResult`.

Comment: What do you anticipate to store in your variable of type 'Result'? Result is a type that stores either a success or failure - is this your goal? It does not store the data that gets returned from your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need a few tools in your toolbox when working with server downloading:

1. An [extension by Charlton Provatas](https://gist.github.com/cprovatas/5c9f51813bc784ef1d7fcbfb89de74fe) which I will supply a slightly modified version below.
2. [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com). This one is not as important at the others, but it can save you if a server is sending a badly constructed response.
3. [QuickType](https://quicktype.io) that will give you a start for your decoder.

You weren't too far off what you needed to do, and without these tools I wouldn't have been able to discover the issues. First, I printed out the JSON data response with `prettyPrintedJSONString`:

```
import Foundation

// https://gist.github.com/cprovatas/5c9f51813bc784ef1d7fcbfb89de74fe
extension Data {
    var prettyPrintedJSONString: NSString { /// NSString gives us a nice sanitized debugDescription
        guard let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: []),
              let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: [.prettyPrinted]),
              let prettyPrintedString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else { return "Unable to print" }

        return prettyPrintedString
    }
}
```

The only difference between this extension and the original is that it returns a `String`, not an optional `String` and avoids an irrelevant warning when you use it. This gets used right after the URLSession call like this:

```
// Step 2: Fetching the data for the URL.
do {
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    print(data.prettyPrintedJSONString)
```

This prints your response which you can run through QuickType to get a decoder.

Now, let me take a step back to the basics. JSON is a pretty simple format. You are either getting an array or a set of key-value pairs all enclosed in brackets. The decoder goes through this structure and tries to find matches to the decodable model that you supplied. In this case, your `APIResponse`. The type of `apiResults` was wrong at first glance, but I suspect that was a typo, and not an intentional. `Result` is an [enum defined in the language](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) that you aren't using, and really don't need, in this simple example. And, speaking toward your error, it is not `Codable` and would not have decoded this JSON.

One other technique that you should be using is to avoid `try?` unless you are absolutely positive you do not care why it fails, as you throw away the error. I changed your code to:

```
// Step 2: Fetching the data for the URL.
do {
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    print(data.prettyPrintedJSONString)
            
    let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
    // if the try above throws an error, you will never reach the line below.
    // It will go immediately to the `catch`.
    results = decodedResponse.results
} catch {
    // This will print out what happened, and decoder errors are some of the better written error messages.
    // This single change will greatly help you debug this code.
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```

Experience also tells us that the response from Apple was most likely going to be an array of `APIResult`, and not just a single, and printing the JSON confirmed this. There is also a count of the return, and while you don't need it, I through it in for completeness here:

```
struct APIResponse: Codable {
    var results: [APIResult]
    var resultCount: Int
}
```

You will notice I changed your `var apiResults` to `results`. That was intentional. Looking at the JSON shows that Apple returns a key-value pair (in Swift we call it a Dict) that is made of the key "results" and returns an array of `APIResult`. However, the decoder was failing because the key was "results", but it was looking for "apiResults" that was non-existent. We aren't required to change the name of our variables, but we do have to tell the decoder how to find what we are looking for by providing the keys, called `CodingKeys`.

An `APIResult` doesn't decode either because of misnamed variables, but I will fix that with `CodingKeys` here:

```
struct APIResult: Codable {
    var songName: String
    var songID: Int
    var collectionName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case songName = "trackName" // Apple calls it a trackName, not songName
        case songID = "trackId" // Apple calls it a trackId, not songID.
        // Notice the lowercased "d". Case matters in decoding.
        case collectionName
    }
}
```

With these changes, you get:

[image]

I know this was a bit long winded, and hopefully not too pedantic, but understanding the fundamentals is important in being able to debug server calls.