# Why is my Swift UI project not receiving the data via json?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

Im a trying to learn Swift Ui with Json. I want to use a public API to learn it. Unfortunately it always display the error: The data couldnt be read because it isnt in the correct format.

APi documentation here https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/entitaeten/politician
API data here https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians

The code is following

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var politicians: [Politician] = []
    @State private var selectedPolitician: Politician? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(politicians, id: \.id) { politician in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedPolitician = politician
                }) {
                    Text("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Politicians")
            .onAppear {
                self.loadPoliticians()
            }
            
            if let politician = selectedPolitician {
                PoliticianDetailView(politician: politician)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadPoliticians() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let politicians = try decoder.decode([Politician].self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.politicians = politicians
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct PoliticianDetailView: View {
    let politician: Politician
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
                .font(.title)
            Text("ID: \(politician.id)")
            Text("Sex: \(politician.sex)")
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct Politician: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let sex: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case sex
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by changing `print(error.localizedDescription)` to `print(error)`, this will give you a more informative error message

Comment: Paste the JSON onto www.QuickType.io you are missing the parent

Comment: @Joakim My new error is (typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)), thanks for help tip anway :D

Comment: @lorem  I will try it once at home, i used it once and was overwhlemed how big the code was, after it entered it :P

Comment: See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76114311/7129318) that I just finished writing.

Comment: @AlKo For readability, please [edit] your question to add additional info, don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a set of structs that mirror the json data you get from the server. So the error you get is because you are not decoding the json data into the correct struct models.

Once you copy and pasted your json data into https://app.quicktype.io/  you
need to do a bit more work to adapt the generated code for your purpose.

The following decodes the JSON data and puts it into an array of `[Politician]`.
The code also has the newer `NavigationStack` instead of the deprecated `NaviagtionView`.
Works well for me.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var politicians: [Politician] = []
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {  // <--- here
            if politicians.isEmpty { ProgressView() }
            List(politicians, id: \.id) { politician in
                Button(action: {
                    path.append(politician) // <--- here
                }) {
                    Text("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Politicians")
            .navigationDestination(for: Politician.self) { poli in  // <--- here
                PoliticianDetailView(politician: poli)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadPoliticians()
        }
    }
    
    private func loadPoliticians() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/api/v2/politicians")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    // --- here
                    let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(PoliResponse.self, from: data)
                    politicians = results.data  // <--- here
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct PoliticianDetailView: View {
    let politician: Politician
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(politician.firstName) \(politician.lastName)").font(.title)
            Text("ID: \(politician.id)")
            Text("Sex: \(politician.sex ?? "")")  // <--- here
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}


// the response you get from the server
struct PoliResponse: Codable {
    let meta: Meta
    let data: [Politician]
}

struct Politician: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let entityType, label, apiURL, abgeordnetenwatchURL, firstName, lastName: String
    let party: Party
    let sex, birthName, partyPast, education, residence, occupation: String?
    let yearOfBirth, statisticQuestions, statisticQuestionsAnswered: Int?
    let extIDBundestagsverwaltung, qidWikidata, fieldTitle: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, label, sex, party, education, residence, occupation
        case entityType = "entity_type"
        case apiURL = "api_url"
        case abgeordnetenwatchURL = "abgeordnetenwatch_url"
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case birthName = "birth_name"
        case yearOfBirth = "year_of_birth"
        case partyPast = "party_past"
        case statisticQuestions = "statistic_questions"
        case statisticQuestionsAnswered = "statistic_questions_answered"
        case extIDBundestagsverwaltung = "ext_id_bundestagsverwaltung"
        case qidWikidata = "qid_wikidata"
        case fieldTitle = "field_title"
    }
}

struct Party: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let entityType, label, apiURL: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, label
        case entityType = "entity_type"
        case apiURL = "api_url"
    }
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let abgeordnetenwatchAPI: AbgeordnetenwatchAPI
    let status, statusMessage: String
    let result: Result
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status, result
        case abgeordnetenwatchAPI = "abgeordnetenwatch_api"
        case statusMessage = "status_message"
    }
}

struct AbgeordnetenwatchAPI: Codable {
    let version, changelog, licence, documentation: String
    let licenceLink: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case version, changelog, licence, documentation
        case licenceLink = "licence_link"
    }
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let count, total, rangeStart, rangeEnd: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case count, total
        case rangeStart = "range_start"
        case rangeEnd = "range_end"
    }
}
```